# Nuget package restore

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to work out how NuGet knows what packages it needs to restore (and how it knows where to find them) in the case that they are not present locally (i.e. when the packages have not been committed to source control).

I can see in the solution I have a .nuget directory but that basically just contains the NuGet.exe. There's a packages.config in each project, that looks promising, that contains the following (shortened for clarity);

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
 <package id="AutoMapper" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

I was expecting to see a URL pointing to the source of the package. So if Nuget just uses the package id string, how would it know what to do if I had multiple package sources that both list available the same package Id. Is it just through the priority in the package sources?

I ask because I have a package from a local source, I deleted the packages and disabled the package source, cleaned the solution and rebuilt. It worked when I expected it would fail.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 questions in your post, so I'll try to address one by one:

> How NuGet knows what packages it needs to restore?

As you guessed, Nuget uses the .Nuget folder to automatically install missing packages. Inside the .Nuget folder, there is a file named "Nuget.targets" which is basically a VS project file (.csproj) containing this line

```
<RestoreCommand>$(NuGetCommand) install "$(PackagesConfig)" -source "$(PackageSources)" -nocache  $(RequireConsentSwitch) -solutionDir "$(SolutionDir) "</RestoreCommand>
```

which takes the charge to install packages listed in packages.config file in each projects.

> So if Nuget just uses the package id string, how would it know what to do if I had multiple package sources that both list available the same package Id ?

In %appdata%\nuget.config, you can see a list of "package sources" for Nuget: for a given packageId, Nuget will search for it in these package sources in the same order as in nuget.config